# jQuery - Select children with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to count the number of children inside a div using jquery `$(this)` selector and the element's class. And the results are different. I thought jquery's `$(this)` refers to the owner object of function, is there any thing special about `$(this)` that I am missing?

```
$('.parent').ready(function(){
        $('.parent').children().length; // 6
        $(this).children().length; // 1
});
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax error in the 3rd line?

Comment: oh yes, apart from it (I fixed it) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
    $('.parent').children().length; // 6
```

is the correct way to do it.  This:

```
    $(this).children().each(function().length; // 1
```

is a syntax error. If you really wanted to iterate through the children you could use ".each()" but you'd have to do it properly:

```
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      var $child = $(this);
      // ...
    });
```

Note that inside the ".each()" callback, `this` will refer to each child in succession as the function is called by jQuery.

Comment: Your $(this).children().each(function() {}); doesnt work for me

Comment: Well as written in the example, it doesn't do anything; what do you want it to do?  That's **not** the way to count the number of children; it **is** a way to perform some operation on each child element however.

Comment: ok sure $.each() is not a (good) way to count the number of children and I wasnt asking about $.each() anyway. I was asking about the difference of $('.parent') and $(this) in $('.parent').ready() function. I thought those two selectors would be the same but seems like I was wrong, any idea?

Comment: Well `$('.parent')` selects **all** elements with class "parent".  Inside the ".each()" function, `this` will refer to a single element. The "ready()" handler **always** applies to the whole document, regardless of what selector you use, so in the "ready" handler `this` will not refer to your element at all.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` inside the `$('.parent').ready()` method refers to `$('.parent')` object.

`$(this)` inside the `each()` method of the `children()` collection refers to the current child iterated.

So the way to achieve same number (for whatever reasons you have) is:

```
$('.parent').ready(function(){
   var directLength = $(this).children().length; // 6
   var indirectLength = 0;
   $(this).children().each(function(){
      indirectLength++;
   });

   alert([directLength, indirectLength].join("\n"));
});
```

Edit: your comments can have only one meaning: you have 6 elements with class `parent` and each of those have only one child. So I assume you're want to count the parent elements, here is proper code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var directLength = $('.parent').length; // 6
   var indirectLength = 0;
   $('.parent').each(function() {
      indirectLength++;
   });

   alert([directLength, indirectLength].join("\n"));
});
```

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. I ran your function and it gave me "1 1", any idea? I totally agree the result should be be "6 6" but perhaps there is something weird about $(this) that I havent known yet

Comment: @Nguy I think I understand now.. see my edit. The `$('.parent')` is the collection of all six elements with that class, I think you want to iterate each of them separately?

Comment: @Shadow Iterating is simple with $('.parent').each(function() {}), I just wonder why the $(this) in $('.parent').ready() doesnt behave in the same way. $(this), in my question sample code, is not a collection of 6 elements ( $(this).children().length; returns 1)

Comment: @Ngu because `$(this)` in your code refers to the current element with class "parent", the `ready()` method is applied on each of them separately.

Comment: then, if I have, say, a div with class (or id) "parent" and I want to count the number of its children (or perform some function) within $("parent").ready() function, is there any way I can do that with the 'this' keyword?